# R character match and rank

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have a character vector

```
var1 <- c("pine tree", "dense forest", "red fruits", "green fruits",
                 "clean water", "pine")
```

and a list

```
var2 <- list(c("tall tree", "fruits", "star"),  c("tree tall", "pine tree",
  "tree pine", "black forest", "water"), c("apple", "orange", "grapes"))
```

I want to match words in var1 with elements in var2, and obtain the ranked elements of var2. For example, the desired output here is:

```
"tree tall"    "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "black forest" "water"
```

var2[2] is rank 1 (4 phrases in var1: pine tree, dense forest, pine, and water matches with var2[2]

```
"tall tree" "fruits"    "star"
```

var2[1] is rank 2, (3 phrases in var1: pine tree, red fruits, and green fruits matches with var2[1])

```
 "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

var2[3] is rank 3 which has no match with var1

I tried

```
indx1 <- sapply(var2, function(x) sum(grepl(var1, x)))
```

without getting the output desired.

How to solve it? A code snippet would be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:

The new data is given below:

```
var11 <- c("nature" ,  "environmental", "ringing", "valley" ,            "status" ,            "climate" ,          
       "forge"  ,            "environmental" ,     "common" ,           
       "birdwatch",          "big"    ,            "link" ,             
       "day" ,              "pintail"    ,        "morning" ,          
       "big garden" ,        "birdwatch deadline", "deadline february" ,
       "mu condition" ,        "garden birdwatch" ,  "status" ,           
       "chorus walk" ,       "dawn choru"  ,       "walk sunday", 
       "climate lobby" ,     "lobby parliament" ,  "u status" ,              
       "sandwell valley" ,   "my status of"  ,           "environmental lake")


var22 <- list(c("environmental condition"),  c("condition", "status"), c("water", "ocean water"))
```

Comment: I checked your second example. For the 1st element, there are 3 matches, for environment, and for 2nd element again there are 3 matches for status.  So, this again a tie

Comment: I have edited var11 and now there are only TWO status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over 'var2' (`sapply(var2,`) , split the strings at white space (`strsplit(x, ' ')`), `grep` the output list elements as pattern for 'var1'.  Check if there is `any` match, `sum` the logical vector and `rank` it.  This can be used for reordering the 'var2' elements.

```
 indx <- rank(-sapply(var2, function(x) sum(sapply(strsplit(x, ' '),
              function(y) any(grepl(paste(y,collapse='|'), var1))))),
                 ties.method='first')
 indx
 #[1] 2 1 3


var2[indx]
#[[1]]
#[1] "tree tall"    "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "black forest" "water"       

#[[2]]
#[1] "tall tree" "fruits"    "star"     

#[[3]]
#[1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

#### Update

If we need to count the duplicates as well, try

```
indx <- rank(-sapply(var22, function(x) sum(sapply(strsplit(x, ' '), 
        function(y) sum(sapply(strsplit(var11, ' '), 
          function(z) any(grepl(paste(y, collapse="|"), z))))))),
             ties.method='random')
indx
#[1] 1 2
```

#### Update2

If we need to filter out the elements in 'var2' that don't have any match with 'var1'

```
pat <- paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(var1, ' '))), collapse="|")
Filter(function(x) any(grepl(pat, x)), var2[indx])
#[[1]]
#[1] "tree tall"    "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "black forest" "water"       

#[[2]]
#[1] "tall tree" "fruits"    "star"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78694/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-r-character-match-and-rank).

Comment: Thanks bluefeet for moving our conversation to chat. Meanwhile, the Filter  problem remains, and Filter needs to be replaced.

Comment: @john Try `var2[indx][sapply(var2[indx], function(x) any(grepl(pat,x)))]`

Answer (score 0):

The following code could work:

```
idx <- rank(-sapply(var2, 
         function(x) sum(unlist(sapply(strsplit(var1,split=' '), 
           function(y) any(unlist(sapply(y,
             function(z) grepl(z,x))>0))>0)))),
  ties.method='random')
```